# Why does a light switch blow fuse when over certain voltage not affected by other usage on same fuse

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, light-fixture

I just moved into an apartment that has ceiling wired up but no light fixture installed. So I brought a rail led light fixture from home depot and tried to install it. When I turn it on the switch, it blows fuse. I brought another fixture from Ikea in case there's something wrong with the previous fixture but the fuse still blows. So I did some testing.

The switch is 3 way, there is a dimer switch on one side and another switch on another wall. If I put one Ikea led 4.3w light blub on the rail, it works fine. If I put 2 light blubs on, it will blow fuse, but if I dim it to certain amount, it will work. 3 and more light blubs will not work regardless of dimming. Next I tested this with the other light switches that uses the same fuse (the fuse also have outlets but I don't believe any of them are being used). With the other light switches, there are 9 led lights in total which lights up the kitchen and door way. Regardless of the kitchen and doorway lights being on or not, the new ceiling light still works with 1 light blub and 2 light blubs at the same dimming level as the previous test, but blows the fuse when I up the dimmer or use more than 2 blubs. It seems the total amount of voltage is not blowing the fuse, but the amount of voltage in the one light switch that is blowing the fuse. I cannot figure out the explanation for this.

I had actually hired an electrician and paid $300 for this, he looked at it for 2 hours. At the end he think he fixed a nick somewhere and blame the light fixture and that is why I am testing this with 2 different light rails, but I doubt that both light rails are failing and if it's a nick it should of blow fuse right away and not work with even one light blub,  I think logically, I don't know much about these things. I am scared to get the guy again or call another electrician, it's so expensive...

One more thing to mention. I went back to home depot saying the light fixture is tripping the fuse, so the home depot electrician tested it and it works fine with any light blubs.

I would be grateful if anyone can help resolve this mystery.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?  My _guess_ is that there are two circuits involved, and your light is wired connecting them, giving 240 volts.  If you don't have a voltmeter, one thing you could try to test this is turning off all the circuit breakers _except_ the one for this light.  If it still blows the circuit, then I'm wrong, but if it doesn't blow, or the light doesn't come on at all, then you would need to find which other circuit is involved.  You could turn on the other breakers one by one, and see which one needs to be on for turning on the light to trip the breaker.

Comment: Light bulbs of any type need more than 15 one amp bulbs to get close to blowing/tripping a fuse/breaker.  More likely you have wired it wrong or there is a high amperage device also on that circuit that is taking too much power and the lights take it over.

Comment: @BaddDadd I do have a voltmeter and tested it and it is 120 volts only

Comment: It is an apartment after all and it is 2 years old. There is a chance somehow they hook the wires wrong like to another unit or outside. The cable guy did say the apartment have a messed up routing for the cable and had to work around it. But how do I even find if it wires are routed somewhere wrong? Is there a way for me to trace the wires through the walls/ceiling?

Comment: I am going to turn off all my electric appliances and see if power is still being consumed to check if something is pulling power somewhere that I not know of and do the breaker test that badddadd mentioned.

Comment: I also wonder if it is possible to have a wired nicked somewhere but it is somehow being absorbed until I turn up the amp/voltage